# iOS How to get button text from tableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using simple tableview and i have add button in every cell , The Problem is how to get button text from cell number second and any other cell number get button text i am using this code but its not working

```
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];

             UITableViewCell *cell = [tbl_view cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

              for( UITableViewCell *getview in cell.subviews)
              {
                  if([getview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
                  {
                      NSLog(@"sdfsdfsd");
                      // UIButton *button = (UIButton *);
                  }
              }
```

This code is set button in tableview cell

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {

        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        UILabel *fromLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 5, 250,20)];
        if (cell == nil) {

            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] init];

        }

        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    UIButton *button_chaeckbox = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button_chaeckbox.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        button_chaeckbox.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 15, 15);

        if( [checkedArray containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row]])
        {
             [button_chaeckbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }else
        {

        [button_chaeckbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"empty_box_b.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
 [button_chaeckbox setTitle:@"creaButtonname" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button_chaeckbox.tag=indexPath.row;
        [button_chaeckbox addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(checkboxAction:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [cell addSubview:button_chaeckbox];
    }
```

Please give me solution , i have try this code in ios 7 and ios 8 this is not working 
Regards, 
Nishant Chandwani

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing give tag value for each button like

> button_chaeckbox.tag=indexpath.row

in cellForRowAtIndexPath Method .

> in checkboxAction do like this
>   NSString * titleText=sender.titleLabel.text

and you will check in button action method from which cell it is

> like using conditions if(sender.tag == //your cell number second value//)

I think you want like this only .

Answer (score 1):

**Use this code for reuse cells in table view**

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {

        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {

            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
            UILabel *fromLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 5, 250,20)];
            cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            UIButton *button_chaeckbox = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            button_chaeckbox.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            button_chaeckbox.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 15, 15);
            [button_chaeckbox addTarget:self
                                 action:@selector(checkboxAction:)
                       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            [cell addSubview:button_chaeckbox];
button_chaeckbox.tag=1001;
        }
        if( [checkedArray containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row]])
        {
            [button_chaeckbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }else
        {

            [button_chaeckbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"empty_box_b.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }


    }
```

**Use this code for get button from cell**

```
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];

             UITableViewCell *cell = [tbl_view cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIButton *button_chaeckbox=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithtag:1001]
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this**

**In** `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
[cell.button setTitle:@"RAM" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
cell.button.tag=indexPath.row;
[cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(cellBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**Selector method**

```
-(void)cellBtn :(UIButton *)sender
{
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];
     AlertCustomCell *cell = [tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     NSString *user = cell.button.titleLabel.text;
     NSLog(@"Text of button is :%@",user);
}
```

I hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making a `UITableViewCell` subclass and making the button a a property on that subclass. Then in your code would look something like this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    UILabel *fromLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 5, 250,20)];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    UIButton *button_chaeckbox = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button_chaeckbox.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    button_chaeckbox.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 15, 15);

    if( [checkedArray containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row]])
    {
         [button_chaeckbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    } else {

         [button_chaeckbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"empty_box_b.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    [button_chaeckbox addTarget:self
               action:@selector(checkboxAction:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell setCellButton:button_chaeckbox];
    return cell;
}
```

**And then to get the button:**

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];

CustomTableCell *cell = (CustomTableCell *)[tbl_view cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

UIButton * yourButton = cell.CellButton
```

Comment: CustomTableViewCell and [cell setCellButton:button_chaeckbox]; give me error how i set

Comment: Have you created a `CustomTableViewCell` class with a property `CellButton`

Answer (score 0):

let me point out one thing. if you want to traverse through all the subviews of the table cell you have to make `for( UITableViewCell *getview in cell.subviews)` to `for( UIView *getview in cell.subviews)`

The code would look like this

```
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];

         UITableViewCell *cell = [tbl_view cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

          for( UIView *getview in cell.subviews)
          {
              if([getview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
              {
                  UIButton *button = (UIButton *)getView;
                  NSLog @("%@",button.titleLabel.text)
              }
          }
```